# An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel, tiny-tds

I am fetching data using tiny tds. While fetching am getting following error. Am not using eclipse. Am using Mongrel server + Windows

```
     Read error: #<Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.>
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ming

    w32/lib/mongrel/http_response.rb:140:in `write'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ming
    w32/lib/mongrel/http_response.rb:140:in `write'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ming
    w32/lib/mongrel/http_response.rb:98:in `send_header'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/handle
    r/mongrel.rb:88:in `process'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ming
    w32/lib/mongrel.rb:165:in `block in process_client'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ming
    w32/lib/mongrel.rb:164:in `each'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ming
    w32/lib/mongrel.rb:164:in `process_client'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ming
    w32/lib/mongrel.rb:291:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi, have you resolved this problem? I'm facing the same problem with you. I did a lot of google and didn't find any clues.

Comment: No error is still coming, but my functionality is working fine even error is coming..strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem: the server log has this error message and client gets Timeout exception. Finally we got the root cause: we send base64-encoded string of an image from the web server to the client. This base64 string may interrupt with the separator codes of the HTTP response and crash the web server. After we removed the base64 string, it works fine.

Comment: I'm having the same issue described in the problem, but the url and cookie I set are both UTF-8.  I'm using a get request.